# Possible to lock attribute write access by Doors User?

Tags: scripting, ibm-doors

Is it possible to programmatically lock certain attributes based on the user?
So certain attributes can be written to by User2 and certain attributes cannot be written to by User2. However, User1 may have write access to all attributes.

What is the most efficient way of accomplishing this? I have to worry about not taking up too many computational resources, as I would like this to be able to work on quite large modules.

Comment: What are you trying to script here? You can set those permissions easily in the module on the edit attributes dialog. But if you are trying to go through all your current modules and update them accordingly then yes you can do that also.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=14466620&#14466620